# Buffer Error Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to fetch data using json parser but i am getting the buffer error,parsing
 error etc.Pleases help me,codes are given below.......

**log cat**....

```
12-03 11:47:20.175: E/Buffer Error(4082): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 11:47:20.175: E/JSON Parser(4082): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-03 11:47:20.175: W/dalvikvm(4082): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc7d0)
12-03 11:47:20.175: E/AndroidRuntime(4082): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
12-03 11:47:20.185: I/global(4082): Default buffer size used in BufferedWriter constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
12-03 11:47:20.195: I/klogd(117): [ 9721.632072] Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
12-03 11:47:20.225: I/global(4082): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
12-03 11:47:20.275: W/System.err(4082): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
12-03 11:47:20.285: I/global(4082): Default buffer size used in BufferedWriter constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:131)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-03 11:47:20.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     ... 4
```

**Activity Class**..........

```
    package com.example.androidhive;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

        // url to get all products list
        private static String url_all_products =//"http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php"; 
          "http://10.0.2.2:80/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
        private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

        // products JSONArray
        JSONArray products = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

            // Hashmap for ListView
            productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Loading products in Background Thread
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();

            // Get listview
            ListView lv = getListView();

            // on seleting single product
            // launching Edit Product Screen
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                            .toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            EditProductActivity.class);
                    // sending pid to next activity
                    in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                    // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                    startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                }
            });

        }

        // Response from Edit Product Activity
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            // if result code 100
            if (resultCode == 100) {
                // if result code 100 is received 
                // means user edited/deleted product
                // reload this screen again
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }

        /**
         * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
         * */
        class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            int success;
            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            /*  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show(); */
            }

            /**
             * getting All products from url
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG

                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            productsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // no products found
                        // Launch Add New product Activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                NewProductActivity.class);
                        // Closing all previous activities
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                //pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                        TAG_NAME},
                                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }

        }

    }

Php file.......  

 <?php
    //header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    /*
     * Following code will list all the products
     */

    // array for JSON response
    $response = array();


    // include db connect class
    require_once('db_connect.php');

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // get all products from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node
        $response["products"] = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            // temp user array
            $product = array();
            $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
            $product["name"] = $row["name"];
            $product["price"] = $row["price"];
            $product["description"] = $row["description"];
            $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
            $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];



            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["products"], $product);
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // echoing JSON response
        print json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no products found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No products found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>






Php file.......  

 <?php
    //header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    /*
     * Following code will list all the products
     */

    // array for JSON response
    $response = array();


    // include db connect class
    require_once('db_connect.php');

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // get all products from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node
        $response["products"] = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            // temp user array
            $product = array();
            $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
            $product["name"] = $row["name"];
            $product["price"] = $row["price"];
            $product["description"] = $row["description"];
            $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
            $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];



            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["products"], $product);
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // echoing JSON response
        print json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no products found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No products found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is your actual JSON Response ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..  You cannot pass the `intent` in **doInBackground**

```
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, int> {
            int success;
            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            /*  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show(); */
            }

            /**
             * getting All products from url
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG

                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            productsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        success = 0;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return success;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(int success) {

                if (success == 1) {
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                        TAG_NAME},
                                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                  }else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(AllProductsActivity.this,
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Find the IP Address:
Type in ipconfig in command prompt:

[image: Find IP Address]

2) Make sure it works by typing in your IP address/android_connect/get_all_products.php into you browser. For example, for me it’s “http://192.168.1.79/android_connect/get_all_products.php”
If it works, u should see this:

[image: PHP Right Message]

If you’re like me, you see this:
[image: PHP Error Message]

So the error message is being sent back with the JSON file and is causing a NullPointerException in the Android code.

3) If you’re getting the PHP error message, turn off the error message reporting.

To change the PHP settings so that the error message doesn’t get return, go here. From taskbar -> Right click on WAMP-> PHP-> php.ini

[image: Php.ini]

Change the text “display_errors= On” to “display_errors= Off”

[image: PHP Settings]